# Remark in "Multiplicative Number Theory" by Davenport

Tags: number-theory

On page 9 in "Multiplicative Number Theory" by 
Davenport, he remarks that 
"It is a remarkable fact that no one has yet given a simple
and direct proof that the value of the finite sum in (7) is
negative, ..."
By the sum in (7) he means
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{q-1}m\left(\frac mq\right),
$$
where $ \left(\frac mq\right) $ is the Legendre symbol and q is a prime $\;3\pmod 4$.

The first edition of this book was published in 1967.
So I thought maybe "a simple and direct
proof" to show the sum is negative is found by now.

I was wondering if someone could tell me the situation 
(or the proof if it's found.)
Thanks!